# Mongoose and localization

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to get your advices about mongoose localization, consider i have two languages "en" and "de", and i have two models like this :

```
// Schema of Book
const Book: Schema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, i18n: true },
});

Book.plugin(mongooseI18n, {
  locales: ["en", "de"],
});

export default mongoose.model("Book", CategorySchema);

// Schema of author
const Author:Schema : new Schema({
    name: { type: String, i18n: true }
})
Author.plugin(mongooseI18n, {
  locales: ["en", "de"],
});
...
```

From the documentation this will generate me : {name:{ en : String, de:String }}, till there i understand.
If i want to reference book to author, how can achieve this? something like this is possible ? :

```
// Schema of Book
const Author: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, i18n: true },
    book:{ type:Object, i18n: true }
});
...
```

Is this will do something like : book : { en:Object, de:Object } ? or have you any idea ? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you say: If i want to reference book to author, how can achieve this?

Based on documentation could something like this work?

```
Author.find((err, resources) => {
    const localizedResources = Author.schema.methods.toJSONLocalized(resources, 'gb');
});
```